# Update data in Word when copy from Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with VBA excel and word. I copy a data table from Excel (data is loaded from Database) and paste into Word.When I update value in Excel.How to refresh data in Word 
**Excel**
[image]

**Word**
[image]

When I update value Password2 -> Password3, i wish data will update in word when i click commandbutton in word
[image]

Thank!

Comment: I would probably just clear the Word document and then repaste (move) the table back into Word. I think it would be difficult to figure out what elements changed, versus those that didn't.

Answer (score 0):

When you paste the copied cells into Word, use "[Link & Use Destination Styles](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/paste-options-HA101831692.aspx)" or "[Link & Keep Source Formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/paste-options-HA101831692.aspx)".

This will insert fields that link to the values stored in the Excel file.

Alternatively, you may be able to [link these fields directly to the database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-data-from-access-or-other-data-source-HP005190166.aspx?CTT=1) you are populating Excel from.

Comment: thank for your answer but you can give me  sample code for this

Comment: @jimhawkins You can click the links in my answer to see how this is done without using any code.